# Custom external authentication Asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I am building a web api that uses asp.net identity for authentication.
and I also have and existing user database store that i want to use as an external login provider.

Is there a way that i can create and external login provider like the 
Facebook and Google Authentication is asp.net?

Sample

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication();
app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

What i want is something like

```
app.UseMyOwnAuthentication();
```

Comment: ASP.NET Identity supports local accounts out of the box with EntityFramework db. Migrating your local accounts to that scheme might be an easier solution.